# Python3.x - counting occurences of all substrings using dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, substring

Given some string S, this code will count the number of occurrences of all possible substrings of the string S.

```
#count[i]=no of different substrings in the string that occurs exactly i times
count=[0]*(100001)
a=input()
dic={}
n=len(a)
for i in range(n):
    temp=""
    for j in range(i,n,1):
        temp+=a[j]
        if temp in dic:
            dic[temp]+=1
        else:
            dic[temp]=1
for k,v in dic.items():
    count[v]+=1
```

For example, for the string "ababa", the array will be:

- cnt[1]=4 {"ababa", "abab", "baba", "bab"} occur exactly once
- cnt[2]=4 {"aba", "ab", "ba", "b"} occur exactly twice
- cnt[3]=1 {"a"} occur exactly thrice
- cnt[4]=0
- cnt[5]=0

i am interested in knowing the runtime of my code

Comment: Are you just asking how well this will perform? If that's the case then you should just test it yourself and see how well it works.

Comment: where's  `temp` defined/assigned? And `n` ?

Comment: The complexity does not change based on your string length, what would the worst case be for "foobar"?

Comment: I still can’t make head or tail of what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: @xrisk. I think the OP is counting how many times  all substrings from 1 to n appear in the whole string at at least trying to

Comment: n is the length of the string..i manually tested with input string  'aaaaaaa..........'upto 10^5..it becomes slow..may i know the reason behind this???

Comment: @suren99,  what is n?

Comment: n is the length of the string

Comment: were you able to execute this ? I'm getting Nameerror and also please explain the algorithm of the problem so that it could be easy to understand the problem

Comment: @Praneeth I think this is meant to be either Python3 or `raw_input()`

Comment: @xrisk: right! also its better if he mentions what input user needs to enter is it integer or string

Comment: @Praneeth he also needs to explain what `temp` is and where it should be defined.

Comment: i'm  counting the number of different substrings that occur in the string exactly i times..for if a='bbb' count[1]=1('bbb'occurs once) count[2]='1'('bb' occurs twice) count[3]=1('b' occurs thrice)

Comment: @suren99 what about `temp` ? Please post working code and also tell which python version you are using.

Comment: @xrisk  sorry for that ...updated..temp is the substring which starts from i and ends at j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are essentially two parts of your code to consider separately:

1. The nested loop where you build `dic`.
2. The loop where you build `count`.

**For 1.** there are two loops to consider. The i loop will run `n` times and j loop will run `n-i` times each time.

This means that the j loop will run `n` times the first time, `n-1` times the second time and so on till it runs once when `i = n-1`. Thus the total running time of this block is n(n+1)/2, which is O(n^2).

(Note: I am assuming that the dictionary access take constant time which is the case most of the time).

**For 2.** There is only one loop to consider which will run for as many times unique substrings exist. For a string of length n, the maximum number of unique substrings is again n(n+1)/2, which is also O(n^2).

So, running time is O(n^2). For n = 10e5, the number of operations is ~10e10, which will take around 10 seconds, using the standard assumption that 10e9 operations take 1 second.

Comment: for the string  'aaaaa......a'(length=5000) it takes about about 37 secs.why is it so?

Comment: Because "I am assuming that the dictionary access take constant time"